# Exclude text from Arrays in Sum Product

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to exclude text from arrays in a SUMPRODUCT function.

The formula I am using is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("S",Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100)),(Schedule!$AT12:DP12>=D29)*(Schedule!AT12:DP12<=E29)*(Schedule!$A14:A100="VP")*((Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100)))`

- `Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100`: contains numbers and S (or s)
- `Schedule!$AT12:DP12`: contains dates
- `D29` contains a date
- `Schedule!AT12:DP12`: contains dates
- `E29` contains a date
- `Schedule!$A14:A100`: contains various text of which I only want lines with VP in them included.

If I change `Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100` to `Schedule!$AT$14:$DO$100` then it works, so I know if is the `S` in the cell that creates the error. I know I can't multiply an number by an `S`.

I also tried:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100,"S",0),(Schedule!$AT12:DP12>=D29)*(Schedule!AT12:DP12<=E29)*(Schedule!$A14:A100="VP")*((Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100)))`

I also tried, but to no avail.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE(Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100,"S",0)*(Schedule!$AT12:DP12>=D29)*(Schedule!AT12:DP12<=E29)*(Schedule!$A14:A100="VP")*((Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100)))`

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE(Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100,"S",0)*(Schedule!$AT12:DP12>=D29)*(Schedule!AT12:DP12<=E29)*(Schedule!$A14:A100="VP"))`

Basically what I am trying to say is:
If the cell is in a date range and has VP in the line then add up the cells in the range `AT14:DP100` on the Schedule Sheet. So it will be the `sum of [number x 1(true) x 1(true) x 1(true)] + [number x 0(false) x 1(true) x 1(true)]...`

Where am I going wrong? I feel I may need to use an array formula (CTRL SHIFT and ENTER)

Comment: I think some sample data would have really helped this question

Comment: some sample data would be helpful. What happens when you run the different parts of the combined formula? Troubleshooting the separate components would be the useful thing to do I'd say. Not sure if you'll get 1 and 0's without using IF in the formula's. (I'd expect to be using IF(Schedule!$A14:A100="VP",1,0) in your product formula)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the number of functions that won't automatically operate as Arrays in a `SUMPRODUCT`, you probably need to use an Array Formula. (i.e. use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Fortunately, you're *already* done all the heavy lifting involved.  All we're going to do is re-write your current `SUMPRODUCT(<Condition>,<Values>)` as `{SUM(IF(<Condition>,<Values>,0))}`:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("S",Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100)),(Schedule!$AT12:DP12>=D29)*(Schedule!AT12:DP12<=E29)*(Schedule!$A14:A100="VP")*((Schedule!$AT$14:$DP$100)),0))}
```